# Is it possible to dispatch action through keyboard handler in React-Quill?

Tags: reactjs, quill, react-quill

I have a chat input created with React-Quill and I would like to change the behavior of 'Enter' key press - from adding a new line to dispatching an action. However for some reason I am unable to do so - see this [playground](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/festive-ives-kg3rpq-7scrt2?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltempvv600062a6au88antli%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltempvv600022a6ayy7mb8ww%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltempvv600042a6ayfwfi9l4%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltempvv600052a6als3tj5tr%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltempvv600022a6ayy7mb8ww%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltempvv600022a6ayy7mb8ww%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltfezxcs00022a6a479ko3zt%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltfezxcs00022a6a479ko3zt%2522%257D%252C%2522cltempvv600052a6als3tj5tr%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltempvv600052a6als3tj5tr%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltemq6ha00a32a6adb6xqxzo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltemq6ha00a32a6adb6xqxzo%2522%257D%252C%2522cltempvv600042a6ayfwfi9l4%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltempvv600042a6ayfwfi9l4%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltemq3u1007z2a6akgrvffgs%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltempvv600032a6a8t7veqrh%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cltempws9000sdif8ciif8kx1%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltemq3u1007z2a6akgrvffgs%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Code is here:

```js
function Editor() {
  const [code, setCode] = useState("initial text");
  const [fakeStore, fakeDispatch] = useState("nothing");

  const send = (text) => {
    fakeDispatch(text);
  };

  const modulesSend = {
    keyboard: {
      bindings: {
        custom: {
          key: "Enter",
          handler: send,
        },
      },
    },
  };

  const memoModulesSend = useMemo(
    () => ({
      keyboard: {
        bindings: {
          custom: {
            key: "Enter",
            handler: send,
          },
        },
      },
    }),
    [],
  );

  const handleProcedureContentChange = (content, delta, source, editor) => {
    setCode(content);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>{fakeStore}</p>
      1
      <ReactQuill
        theme="snow"
        modules={modulesSend}
        onChange={handleProcedureContentChange}
      />
      2
      <ReactQuill
        theme="snow"
        defaultValue={code}
        modules={memoModulesSend}
        onChange={handleProcedureContentChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

I know that modules sometimes need memoization, but it didn't help here. Why does the browser crash when the handler calls a normal function in body of the component?